# Jquery Ajax error for asp.net page

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I have a very simple page and a `[WebMethod]` inside it which returns a simple message. I would like to show this message through `$.ajax` on client side. however my website is using rewrites rules so my url becomes readable to user.

EX: 
    Actual webpage: www.mysite.com/about // which has about folder and a user control inside it

there is no aspx page for this instead i am using a method which gets a webpage data which is actual html page and show the content on user control.

here is Jquery part.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.info a').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/about/showServer', //which url to put here
            async: true,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (result) {
                alert("result.d");
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(textStatus);
            },
        });
    });
});
```

C#

```
[WebMethod] // this method is in the user control
      public static string showServer()
      {
            return "Hello from server";
      }
```

How to call this method from client using $.ajax

appreciate your time and help.

## EDITS

I have this structure for my website

mysite.com/about

/about/defualt.aspx --> which loads the user controls

user controls resides in

mysite.com/ConLib/Custom/about.ascx/showServer

So i set it to like this

url: '/ConLib/Custom/about.ascx/showServer',

BUT i see error in chrome developer tool in XHR request "404 error" because when you type mysite.com/conlib/blah blah ..reqrites does not allows this and throws 404 error..

Comment: Is using webservice? If yes, you removed the comment of this line? [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]

Comment: no i amusing normal method

Comment: Where is your webmethod? In an MVC controller or Webforms aspx page?

Comment: webforms..in ascx ..see my edits please

Answer (score 1):

Your ajax `success` method should be this:

```
alert(result.d);
```

Instead of this:

```
success: function (result) {
    alert("result.d");
}
```

and `url` should be:

```
url: "Default.ascx/showServer",   // UserControlPage/MethodName
```

Comment: now its shows "Error" in alert box..when i see in chrome developer tool i see this Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Unknown web method showServer. Parameter name: methodName.. i check the method name and its exactly same i mentioned in my jquery –

Comment: What is the url path you have set?

Comment: How do you register your user control in `defualt.aspx` page? What is the path set there?

Comment: thorugh regiter directive in pgae

Comment: What is the **`Src`** you have set for that `<%@ Register %>` directive??

Comment: <%@ Reference Control="MyUserControl.ascx" %>

Comment: Is it `MyUserControl.ascx` or `about.ascx`?

Comment: about.ascx, i just mentioned it like that

Answer (score 1):

you need to decorate your web method

```
  [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
  public static string showServer()
  {
        return "Hello from server";
  }
```

Comment: now its shows "Error" in alert box..when i see in chrome developer tool i see this Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Unknown web method showServer.
Parameter name: methodName..  i check the method name and its exactly same i mentioned in my jquery

Comment: try mysite.com/about/showServer or localhost/about/showServer as the url

Comment: url: 'localhost/ConLib/Custom/about.ascx/showServer/'   add the / on the end?

Comment: you added the data: "{}"  ?

Comment: and does your localhost have a port number for example localhost:40899/ConLib/Custom/about.ascx/showServer

Answer (score 1):

If your WebMethod is inside a User Control, then it needs to be moved to the ASPX page. See this post:

[How to call an ASP.NET WebMethod in a UserControl (.ascx)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5638184/call-webmethod-in-user-control)

The `url:` param should be in the form of `'/MyPage.aspx/showServer'`